# more than 1 foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models: http://slexy.org/view/s20T8yOiKZ

```
from mxutils.cms_services import generate_secid
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms

class World(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    secid = models.SlugField(max_length=1000, editable=False)
    elements = models.ManyToManyField("Element", related_name='elements', blank=True, null=True)
    metadata = models.OneToOneField("Category_metadata", blank=True, null=True)
    def save(self):
        if not self.pk:
            super(World, self).save()
            self.secid = generate_secid(self.title, self.pk, World.objects.all())
        return super(World, self).save()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.title

class Element(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(World, related_name='element_parent')
    world = models.ForeignKey(World, related_name='world', blank=True, null=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey("Item", blank=True, null=True)
    value = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
    def save(self):
        if self.world and self.item:
            return None
        elif not self.world and not self.item:
            return None
        else:
            return super(Element, self).save()
    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.world:
            return "%s" % self.world.title
        else:
            return "%s" % self.item.title

class ElementInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Element
    extra=1

class WorldAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ElementInline,]
    list_display = ('title',)
    ordering = ['title']
    search_fields = ('title',)
```

When I try to click add button for worlds in admin page it shows me the following error:

> class 'cms_sample.world_models.Element' has more than 1 ForeignKey to class 'cms_sample.world_models.World'.

I think it's something to do with inline. 
What can it be?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Django doesn't know which of the two foreign keys (parent and world) is to be inlined using the `ElementInline`.

```
class ElementInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Element
    fk_name = 'parent' #or 'world', as applicable.
    extra=1
```

Comment: `parent` (or `world`) will need to be in quotes